# Waist and the horse in one

Tags: kung-fu, fist

From the 1972 martial arts film "The Way of the Dragon" written, directed and acted by Bruce Lee. It was also mentioned in the dialogue between Zhou Xingchi and Wu Mengda in " Shaolin soccer " . [1](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%85%B0%E9%A9%AC%E5%90%88%E4%B8%80/8587845#:%7E:text=%E8%85%B0%E9%A9%AC%E5%90%88%E4%B8%80%E6%98%AF,%E5%8F%8C%E8%85%BF%E5%8F%AB%E5%81%9A%E2%80%9C%E9%A9%AC%E2%80%9D%E3%80%82)

I am translating the Chinese to English using google from this web site [Waist and horse in one](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%85%B0%E9%A9%AC%E5%90%88%E4%B8%80/8587845#:%7E:text=%E8%85%B0%E9%A9%AC%E5%90%88%E4%B8%80%E6%98%AF,%E5%8F%8C%E8%85%BF%E5%8F%AB%E5%81%9A%E2%80%9C%E9%A9%AC%E2%80%9D%E3%80%82) I can't find anything similar or official from English source.

The unity of the waist and the horse is mainly a requirement for the strength of the fist. "Horse" means walking on two legs, sometimes horse gait . In Nanquan, the hands are called "bridges" and the legs are called "horses". "Waist and horse in one" means that when exerting strength, the strength of the waist and the strength of the legs should form a joint force, so as to attack the opponent with a more complete whole strength.

The unity of waist and horse is a term in martial arts, which mainly refers to a requirement for Nanquan to exert strength. Exploding the strength of the waist, the strength of the legs and the strength of the feet together is a way of exerting force in martial arts (fighting).
"Horse" refers to walking on two legs, sometimes directly to the horse 's gait . In Nanquan, the hands are called "bridges" and the legs are called "horses".

The unity of the waist and the horse means that the center of gravity of the human body must cooperate with the limbs; the second is to mobilize the muscles of the body to participate in the blow. For example punching, in order to be fast and powerful, it is necessary to exert the combined effect and coordination of feet, legs, hips, waist and shoulders. And according to the principle of muscle power sequence, the large muscles work first, so that the body changes from static to dynamic, so as to facilitate the body to start: the medium muscles exert force secondly, so that the muscles can obtain a certain speed and the body is further accelerated; the small muscles work last Force is mainly to control the movement route and range of punches. At the same time, at the moment of exerting force, cooperate with exhalation, hold your breath to accumulate strength, and use breath to stimulate force, so as to achieve the integration of mind, energy and force, and finally achieve the goal of increasing the blow.

Question:
Where can i get the source to do this below? i.e. reliable website, youtube

> At the same time, at the moment of exerting force, cooperate with
> exhalation, hold your breath to accumulate strength, and use breath to
> stimulate force, so as to achieve the integration of mind, energy and
> force, and finally achieve the goal of increasing the blow.

Comment: Two things. First, you should quote whatever the translation is, because it's not obvious which words are yours and which are not. Second, what are you trying to ask here? What are you looking for in a sorce?

Comment: @mattm ya source of info